# iframe mixed content in Chrome security block

Tags: google-chrome, iframe

We are facing an issue with iframe in chrome 38.

We have a redirection on server-side behind a load balancer and Chrome thinks that it is a mixed content from https to  http.

Any idea why we are encountering this issue?

This is the error we are seeing in console.log:

[blocked] The page at 'https://sampleurl.com' was loaded over HTTPS, but ran insecure content from 'http://sampleurl.com' this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.

Comment: Ever solve this?

Comment: Ever solved this?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your iframe src is a URL started with 'https://'